# How to pass value to another .ftl (freemarker) file?

Tags: freemarker

In my `main.ftl` file I have:

```
<Product>
    <#include "product.ftl">
</Product>
```

and then in `product.ftl`file I have:

```
<#if product.value ??>
    <Value>${product.value}</Value>
</#if>
```

However I would like to know that `product.ftl` was called from `main.ftl` file, not from another e.g `otherFile.ftl`. How can I pass value from `main.ftl` to `product.ftl`?

I tried with:

```
<Product>
    <#assign name=final>
    <#include "product.ftl">
</Product>
```

and then:

```
<#if product.value ?? && name = "final">
    <Value>${product.value}</Value>
</#if>
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `main.ftl` added: 
`<#assign isFinal=true>`
then in `product.ftl` added:

```
<#if product.value ?? && isFinal?? && isFinal>
<Value>${product.value}</Value>
</#if>
```

and now it works.